# How to create Page objects with KIF?

Tags: objective-c, kif, integration-testing

i have problem with classes that extends KIFTestActor, i want to have PageObject per screen, but seems that these objects cannot be initialized normally.

"tester" is a macro that register handler for exceptions, but if i want to do it manually, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to create page objects unless you wrap those in macro.
Here is a detailed description: 
https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/853